# In simple_html_dom how do I find first-level <divs> within div.classname

Tags: php, find, simple-html-dom

I'm using simple_html_dom
I have some html in a php var $text:

```
<div class="aClass">
  <div>
    ...some html
    <div class="anotherClass">
      ..more html
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    ...some html
    <div class="anotherClass">
      ..more html
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I know I can select the outermost div with
`$text->find("div.aClass")`
Instead I want to select all the first level divs within that div so I can process them as part of a `foreach` loop
Something like:

```
foreach ($text->find("div.aClass div") as $myDiv) {
// do stuff with $myDiv
}
```

but that seems to select **all** divs, including those with `class="anotherClass"`

Any help much appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use then child combinator selector `>` which selects only the elements that are direct children of a parent.

```
div.aClass > div
```

For example

```
$html = <<<HTML
<div class="aClass">
  <div>
    ...some html
    <div class="anotherClass">
      ..more html
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    ...some html
    <div class="anotherClass">
      ..more html
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
HTML;

$text = str_get_html($html);

foreach ($text->find("div.aClass > div") as $myDiv) {
    echo $myDiv->innertext() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output

```
 ...some html     <div class="anotherClass">       ..more html     </div>   
 ...some html     <div class="anotherClass">       ..more html     </div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, @the-fourth-bird, that did it! I've learned something new:)